# arrays in Ruby, how to handle this situation?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I have the following array:

```
arr = ["", "2121", "8", "myString"]
```

I want to return false in case the array contains any non-digit symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If empty strings are allowed:

```
def contains_non_digit(array)
    !array.select {|s| s =~ /^.*[^0-9].*$/}.empty?
end
```

Explanation: this filters the array for all strings that match a regular expression. This regex is true for a string that contains at least one non-digit character. If the resulting array is empty, the array contains no non-digit strings. Finally, we need to negate the result, because we want to know the array *does* contain non-digit strings.

Answer (score 8):

```
arr.all? { |s| s =~ /^\d+$/ }
```

This will check for each element if it consists only of digits (`\d`) – If any of them does not, false will be returned.

**Edit:** You didn't completely specify if the empty string is valid or not. If it is, the line has to be rewritten as follows (as per DarkDust):

```
arr.all? {|s| s =~ /^\d*$/ }
```

Comment: +1, didn't know about `all?`. But if the empty string is allowed, I'd simply go for `s =~ /^\d*$/` instead.

Comment: Same but the other way around: `arr.any? {|s| s =~ /^[^\d]+$/ }`

Comment: Not the same, because it returns true in the case the OP mentions, instead of the requested false. So a negation would be required, which is why I went with `#all?` in the first place. Not to mention that your one only works if the string is completely without numbers, as opposed to just containing at least one non-digit.

Comment: Slightly more concise: `arr.all? { |s| s !~ /\D/ }`